# I'm not suppose to draw, but I really want to; what do I do?

Tags: drawing

People have told me that I'm not allowed to draw humans or animals, so I have stopped, but I desperately want to draw; it's what I love to do.  I tried to stay away from it, but it's just too hard.  So I read more answers to this problem and someone said that ''You're allowed to draw anything without a soul.''

Does that mean I can draw robots, as an example, that look like humans? I just need a way to draw humans. Can I draw a made up thing that looks like a human?

Comment: I don't understand what the question here is; you seem to know and understand the rulings, but you don't like them and are looking for an out. What exactly is the question?

Comment: (S)he clearly wants to know whether opposing opinions exist, and in my experience, there likely is one.

Comment: This question is all about drawing and you have used "prophet-muhammad"  tag.

Comment: Turner painted landscapes, as did Whistler; there's also the whole abstraction movement in the 20th C; theres more to drawing than just the human figure.

Answer (score 0):

https://islamqa.info/en/39806 (TBH i don't really like this website as lets just say it goes too extreme for my liking and the problem with this is that it mixes suni,wahabi and other denominations of islam -_- yeah i know, annoying)

but it is said: 
“…He has explained to you in detail what is forbidden to you, except under compulsion of necessity …”

[al-An’aam 6:119]

soo if you have to draw them for an exam...then i think you should. i think its only not allowed when you try to play God (take his position)

i also wanted to say that for hadiths you need to know which ones are made up and which ones are real, which one has twisted meanings which people create etc. god sent prophets to earth so we can follow them, the thing is that each prophet was sent so you could follow them to the time era that you live in and relate o them. sadly many people create fake hadiths, i hate taking research from online because most of it is sadly Crap and not true...
just if it is not said in the quran that you cannot do it then don't but if its not mentioned in the quran then you have no problems. even with hadiths i just don't trust most of them..... time eras change and so most hadiths don't apply now.
As long as you don't have bad intentions or are playing God, i think your fine to go... but i'm not speaking as a known scolar so yeah...

Answer (score 0):

There are serious problems nowadays in managing and maintaining the credibility of Islamic sources. When Allah allows or forbids something, we should try to understand the wisdom behind it, orelse we'll end up having an Islam interpreted just like non-muslim extremists interpret Islam.
For example, on multiple occasions, the Quran mentions freeing slaves as kaffarah for one's sins. Non-muslims would use these verses to imply that Islam allows slavery. Sticking literally to texts is good sometimes, and bad some other times.

Since the old days, and up until today, christians would have drawings of their saints, of who they claim is Jesus, or of who they claim is Mary, and would bow and kneel to these drawings. They would pray in front of them, and kiss the drawings. (I have witnessed this personally).
Giving the slightest spiritual significance to anything material besides what Allah permitted (like the Kaaba for example) is considered shirk and forbidden in Islam...

As long as your drawings are not given any spiritual significance Inshallah it's okay to draw. It's all about what your intentions are when you draw. I am an Arab Muslim and I'm sure besides the very few scholars who push things to the extreme, if I ask this question to any scholar or sheikh he'd think I'm joking. Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him says:

> Never be extreme regarding religion. Many nations have been destroyed 
>   before you only because of extremism in religion

And

> The Best Of Dealings Are The Ones Done In Moderation

[Here's a good read](https://insideislam.wisc.edu/2012/03/the-middle-path/)

Last but not least, if you still have any doubts, draw, and when you're done, just tear down the paper and throw it away. Do what feels most right to you and know that many schools of Islam do not forbid drawing as long as the drawings are not given any spiritual significance, and are not meant to play God in any possible way.

Allah Knows Best!